# Linux lock down route to avoid changes to the default route

Tags: linux, networking, route

I have a problem that every time I connect my Android phone with USB tethering it hijacks my computer's internet connection. Even if the phone's WIFI is off.

I try to manually remove the default route with

```
sudo route del default enp0s29u1u4
```

but it finds its way back after a few minutes. Is there a way to get this interface to permanently go away?

Or alternatively, is there a way to set my desired interface to be permanent no matter what?

Comment: Isn't connecting the Android with USB Tethering **supposed** to give the unix host a route through the Android? Do you really want to set "Mount as disk drive" or "Charge only" on the Android instead of "USB Tethering"?

Comment: I just want to ssh in.

Comment: Then the problem **is** turning on tethering. SSH is handled by tools in the Android Development Kit and does not require tethering.

Comment: The wifi I use has client isolation and I don't have any way to turn it off. How else can I ssh in?

Answer (score 1):

The automatic network setting is done by software like network manager or wicd.

Either configure it properly, so that it does not automatically change your default route, or switch it off and configure everything by yourself (e.g. via `/etc/network/interfaces` in Debian-based distributions).

Comment: Does wpa_supplicant count as software like network manager or wicd?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a shell envirment to manipulate your android and SSH is actually just a protocol besides with many other menthods like telnet, rsh...

You can have your shell with *adb* tools installed and your usb connection ofcuz, then command:

> adb shell

or you really want to *ssh* into, you need install some ssh-server on your android, more detail [here](http://shiroikuma.com/How%20to%20ssh%20into%20an%20Android%20phone%20over%20USB.html)